# Change the dtype of a set of values in an numpy array in place

Tags: python, numpy

I would really appreciate help with the following. I read data from a csv file to lists of lists, and then change that to a numpy array. I am really struggling however to change a set of values in the numpy array to floats as i would like to add a set of numbers for each row and insert the total as a new element in each row.

I am able to change them and create a copy of the changed data type, but i cant seem to do it in place (In the original numpy array).

Here is a small example of how the data from the csv looks like, and what i am trying to achieve.

```
list_of_lists = [["Africa", "1990", "0", "", "32.6"], ["Asia", "2006", "32.4", "5.5", "46.6"],
                 ["Europe", "2011", "5.4", "", "55.4"]]

array = np.array(list_of_lists)

array[array == ""] = np.nan

print(array)

# This doesnt change it in place

array[:, 2:].astype(np.float32, copy=False)

# And this doesnt as well

array[:, 2:] = array[:,2:].astype(np.float32)
```

I read several questions similar to this, but none of the methods worked for me. I thought it would be as easy as setting `copy = False`, but apparently it isn't...

I would really appreciate a hand and if someone can explain this to me.

Comment: `insert a total in each row` - can't do that in-place.  Adding a new column makes a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the `dtype` in-place.

```
In [59]: arr = np.array(list_of_lists)                                                         
In [60]: arr                                                                                   
Out[60]: 
array([['Africa', '1990', '0', '', '32.6'],
       ['Asia', '2006', '32.4', '5.5', '46.6'],
       ['Europe', '2011', '5.4', '', '55.4']], dtype='<U6')
```

The common dtype of the inputs is a string.

replacing the "" with `nan` puts the string representation in the array:

```
In [62]: arr[arr == ""] = np.nan                                                                                       
In [63]: arr                                                                                   
Out[63]: 
array([['Africa', '1990', '0', 'nan', '32.6'],
       ['Asia', '2006', '32.4', '5.5', '46.6'],
       ['Europe', '2011', '5.4', 'nan', '55.4']], dtype='<U6')
```

Look at a portion of the underlying databuffer:

```
In [64]: arr.tobytes()                                                                         
Out[64]: b'A\x00\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\....'
```

See the actual characters.

A slice of the array is a `view`, but the astype conversion is a new array, with its own data buffer.

```
In [65]: arr[:,2:]                                                                             
Out[65]: 
array([['0', 'nan', '32.6'],
       ['32.4', '5.5', '46.6'],
       ['5.4', 'nan', '55.4']], dtype='<U6')
In [66]: arr[:,2:].astype(float)                                                               
Out[66]: 
array([[ 0. ,  nan, 32.6],
       [32.4,  5.5, 46.6],
       [ 5.4,  nan, 55.4]])
```

You can't write `Out[66]` back to `arr` without it being converted back to string.

You could make an object dtype array:

```
In [67]: arr = np.array(list_of_lists, dtype=object)                                           
In [68]: arr                                                                                   
Out[68]: 
array([['Africa', '1990', '0', '', '32.6'],
       ['Asia', '2006', '32.4', '5.5', '46.6'],
       ['Europe', '2011', '5.4', '', '55.4']], dtype=object)
In [69]: arr = np.array(list_of_lists, dtype=object)                                           
In [70]: arr[arr == ""] = np.nan                                                               
In [71]: arr                                                                                   
Out[71]: 
array([['Africa', '1990', '0', nan, '32.6'],
       ['Asia', '2006', '32.4', '5.5', '46.6'],
       ['Europe', '2011', '5.4', nan, '55.4']], dtype=object)
In [72]: arr[:,2:] = arr[:,2:].astype(float)                                                   
In [73]: arr                                                                                   
Out[73]: 
array([['Africa', '1990', 0.0, nan, 32.6],
       ['Asia', '2006', 32.4, 5.5, 46.6],
       ['Europe', '2011', 5.4, nan, 55.4]], dtype=object)
```

dtype remains object, but the type of the elements can change - that's because object dtype is a glorified (or debased) list.  You gain some flexibility, but loose most of the `numpy` numeric speed.

Structured array (compound dtype) as shown in the other answer is another possibility.  It's easy to make this kind of array when loading a `csv` (with `np.genfromtxt`).  You still can't change dtypes in-place.  And you can't do math across fields of a structured array.

## pandas

```
In [153]: df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)                                                     
In [154]: df                                                                                   
Out[154]: 
        0     1     2    3     4
0  Africa  1990     0       32.6
1    Asia  2006  32.4  5.5  46.6
2  Europe  2011   5.4       55.4
In [156]: df.info()                                                                            
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 5 columns):
0    3 non-null object
1    3 non-null object
2    3 non-null object
3    3 non-null object
4    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```

Convert column dtypes:

```
In [158]: df[2].astype(float)   
In [162]: df[4]=df[4].astype(float)
```

Column 3 needs the `nan` conversion before we can convert that.

```
In [164]: df                                                                                   
Out[164]: 
        0     1     2    3     4
0  Africa  1990   0.0       32.6
1    Asia  2006  32.4  5.5  46.6
2  Europe  2011   5.4       55.4
In [165]: df.dtypes                                                                            
Out[165]: 
0     object
1     object
2    float64
3     object
4    float64
dtype: object
```

There are better `pandas` programmers here; I've focused more on `numpy`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I think Pandas is more suited for purpose then. Would you say it is best to use numpy solely with integers/floats?

Comment: `pandas` uses `numpy` arrays to store its data and indices.  In some cases data for a whole dataframe appears to be a 2d array, in others, each column/Series appears to have its own 1d array.  It readily uses object dtype arrays (for example anything containing strings).

Comment: I've a added a rudimentary `pandas` conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pandas code as well! Really useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a structured array to handle multiple datatypes

```
list_of_lists = [["Africa", "1990", "0", "", "32.6"], ["Asia", "2006", "32.4", "5.5", "46.6"],
                 ["Europe", "2011", "5.4", "", "55.4"]]

temp = np.array(list_of_lists)
temp[temp==''] = 0

dtypes = np.dtype([('name','S10'),
    ('val1', np.float),
    ('val2',np.float),
    ('val3',np.float),
    ('val4',np.float)])

array = np.array(list(map(tuple, temp)), dtype=dtypes)

# Now you can modify the structured array
array[['val3', 'val4']]=20
array[0]['name'] = 'Australia'
```

The problem with this is that you can pretend these are columns, but the answer is no, it's just a structure and shape is `(3,)`, I would recommend switching to pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

array = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)
array.replace('', '0', inplace=True)
array[data.columns[2:]] = array[array.columns[2:]].astype(float)

array.dtypes

# 0 object
# 1 object
# 2 float64
# 3 float64
# 4 float64
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jose! I think Pandas is more fit for purpose.